# Calculus Problem___Prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} u(x,t)=g(t)$ for any $t>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given $g \rightarrow R$ continuous and bounded, let
$$u(x,t)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4 \pi}}\int_{0}^t \frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}g(s)ds$$.

Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} u(x,t)=g(t)$ for any $t>0$.

I tried to fix $t_0>0$, $\epsilon>0$, choose $\sigma>0$ such that 
$$|g(t)-g(t_0)|<\epsilon$$ when$$|t-t_0|<\sigma$$
Then if I showed $$|u(x,t)-g(t_0)| \rightarrow0$$ when $$|t-t_0|<\sigma,x \rightarrow0$$ Then I am done.

But the equation of $u(x,t)$ is a bit complex for me and I don't know how to show $$|u(x,t)-g(t_0)| \rightarrow0$$

Can anyone help? THANKS:)

Comment: It is a good idea to clean up your integral by making the substitution q = 1/(t-s). Note that ds = dq * (t-s)^2. So you get rid of the (t-s)^-3/2 term. The exponential also looks much better. It becomes exp(-(x^2)q/4). If you now take the limit of x -> 0, you see that the exponential becomes a delta-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${u(x,t)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4 \pi}}\int_{0}^t \frac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4(t-s)}}g(s)ds}$

Let's take $\frac{x^2}{4(t-s)}=w^2$. Substituting $s=t-\frac{x^2}{4w^2}$and $ds=\frac{4}{x}(t-s)^{3/2}dw$ and simplifying the above expression we get

At $s=0, w=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4t}}$ and at $x=0, w=0$.

Similarly at $s=t, w=\infty$

$u(x,t)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{4t}}}^\infty{\frac4{x}}e^{-w^2}g(t-\frac{x^2}{4w^2})dw$

Putting $x=0$ we get $u(0,t)=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e(-w^2)g(t)dw$

Also $\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-w^2}dw=1$ (Error Function).

So $u(0,t)=g(t)$